# python script has a problem catching error of rest API call to Jenkins

Tags: python, curl, jenkins, try-catch

I am trying to make rest api call to trigger jenkins job.  this job can exists in 2 states:

1. During the first run you can trigger it with the following call from python script:

> subprocess.call(['curl', '-X', 'POST', '-H',
>   'Jenkins-Crumb:cdf99f1d3924f50d7db20bdb7ca47ff6',
>   'jenkinsPath="https://user_jenkins:d547e0393635027f0f26859211b200cb@jenkins.host/job/Testing/job/script-Testing/view/change-requests/job/PR-115/build'])

2. During the subsequent runs the same job gets a workspace that needs to be wiped so I can trigger it in python like this:

> subprocess.call(['curl', '-X', 'POST', '-H',
>   'Jenkins-Crumb:cdf99f1d3924f50d7db20bdb7ca47ff6',
>   'jenkinsPath="https://user_jenkins:d547e0393635027f0f26859211b200cb@jenkins.host/job/Testing/job/script-Testing/view/change-requests/job/PR-115/buildWithParameters?WIPE_WORKSPACE'])

Since I don't know at which state Jenkins job exists at the time I am running my script, I want to run the job both ways and my desire for the wrong URL to catch the error so it doesn't produce any noise and break my script.

I tried to use the following code for one segment but it fails to catch jenkins error if it encounters it.

```
try:
    subprocess.call(['curl', '-X', 'POST', '-H', 'Jenkins-Crumb:cdf99f1d3924f50d7db20bdb7ca47ff6', 'jenkinsPath="https://user_jenkins:d547e0393635027f0f26859211b200cb@jenkins.host/job/Testing/job/script-Testing/view/change-requests/job/PR-115/buildWithParameters?WIPE_WORKSPACE'])
except OSError:
    print "jenkins job has different set of parameters"
    pass
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you paste the output you're receiving?

Comment: lear:both">java.lang.IllegalStateException: This build is not parameterized!
 at jenkins.model.ParameterizedJobMixIn.doBuildWithParameters(ParameterizedJobMixIn.java:238)

Comment: error dump is much longer, but basically its throwing this excetption.

Comment: The subprocss command itself is not failing, you're seeing an error response from Jenkins, i.e., the subprocess command is executing its job (at POST-ing your request and getting the error response) without error. You'll have to parse the response to figure out if your attempt at Jenkins is working or not.

Comment: If you're receiving a python error, and NOT an error from jenkins, OSError is probably not the error that is being thrown. You could use a a plain except block as `except Exception as e:` and then print `e` to see exactly what error is being thrown and then catching only that.

Comment: Thank you Rahul!  I figured it out using exactly the same thing.  My snippet did look something like this:  subprocess.check_output except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e: